# disable checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Hi Friends I have many Div's every div has few `<li>` there is a check-box in every `<li>` .I want if any check box is checked by user then others check box in others div's will be disable only check box which are siblings of checked check box will not be disabled [image]

As per my current code user can check any checkbox in any line which wrong as per my requirment .You can check my code below or **[check fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3bzuC/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul id="gridFriend">
  <li>

    <div class="checkBox">
      <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><a href="SendGifts.aspx?fnd=1053103047&amp;fb=y&amp;src=ALL"><img width="94" height="93" src="https://graph.facebook.com/1053103047/picture?width=94&amp;height=93" alt=" "></a></div>

  </li>
  <li>

    <div class="checkBox">
      <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><a href="SendGifts.aspx?fnd=1053103047&amp;fb=y&amp;src=ALL"><img width="94" height="93" src="https://graph.facebook.com/1053103047/picture?width=94&amp;height=93" alt=" "></a></div>

  </li>  </li>
  <li>

    <div class="checkBox">
      <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><a href="SendGifts.aspx?fnd=1053103047&amp;fb=y&amp;src=ALL"><img width="94" height="93" src="https://graph.facebook.com/1053103047/picture?width=94&amp;height=93" alt=" "></a></div>

  </li>
  <li>

    <div class="checkBox">
      <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><a href="SendGifts.aspx?fnd=1053103047&amp;fb=y&amp;src=ALL"><img width="94" height="93" src="https://graph.facebook.com/1053103047/picture?width=94&amp;height=93" alt=" "></a></div>

  </li>

</ul>



<ul id="gridFriend">
  <li>

    <div class="checkBox">
      <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><a href="SendGifts.aspx?fnd=1053103047&amp;fb=y&amp;src=ALL"><img width="94" height="93" src="https://graph.facebook.com/1053103047/picture?width=94&amp;height=93" alt=" "></a></div>

  </li>
  <li>

    <div class="checkBox">
      <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><a href="SendGifts.aspx?fnd=1053103047&amp;fb=y&amp;src=ALL"><img width="94" height="93" src="https://graph.facebook.com/1053103047/picture?width=94&amp;height=93" alt=" "></a></div>

  </li>
  <li>

    <div class="checkBox">
      <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><a href="SendGifts.aspx?fnd=1053103047&amp;fb=y&amp;src=ALL"><img width="94" height="93" src="https://graph.facebook.com/1053103047/picture?width=94&amp;height=93" alt=" "></a></div>

  </li>
  <li>

    <div class="checkBox">
      <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><a href="SendGifts.aspx?fnd=1053103047&amp;fb=y&amp;src=ALL"><img width="94" height="93" src="https://graph.facebook.com/1053103047/picture?width=94&amp;height=93" alt=" "></a></div>

  </li>

</ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var mergeFriend = 0;
$('ul#gridFriend input').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        mergeFriend++;
    } else {
        mergeFriend--;
    }
     if (mergeFriend >= 3) {
        $('ul#gridFriend input:not(:checked)').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('ul#gridFriend input:not(:checked)').closest('li').animate({opacity:'0.2'},1000);
        //$('.blkSheet').css('display','block');
    } else {
        $('ul#gridFriend input:not(:checked)').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('ul#gridFriend input:not(:checked)').closest('li').animate({opacity:'1'},200);
        /*$('.friendMergeCont').animate({bottom:'-100px'},200)
        $('.blkSheet').css('display','none');*/
       }
    /* $('.friendMergeCont span.close').click(function(){        

        $('.friendMergeCont').animate({bottom:'-100px'},200)
        //$('.blkSheet').css('display','none');
         }) */
/*  if (mergeFriend == 2) {
        $('.friendMergeCont').animate({bottom:'0'},200)
    }else if (mergeFriend == 1) {
        $('.friendMergeCont').animate({bottom:'-100px'},200)
    }   */

});
```

Comment: Invalid markup same ids are repeated for `ul`, better to change with class.

Comment: @Jai thanks for notice that +1

Comment: please explain the question clearly... what do you mean by others check box in other div? explain it with div number 1 and 2.

Comment: @CJ Ramki for example I Click a checbox in row 1 then in row 2 all the checkbox will be disable

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/3bzuC/13/

Comment: @kamal see an answer posted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22707333/1059101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same ids for multiple elems on a single page is invalid markup and surely can cause some issues in browser, so to overcome this you can change `id='gridFriend'` to `class='gridFriend'`:

```
<ul class="gridFriend">
 .......
</ul>
```

then in jQuery you can do this:

```
$('.gridFriend :checkbox').on('change', function () {
  var $check = $(this);
  $check.closest('.gridFriend').siblings('.gridFriend').find(':checkbox').prop('disabled', true)
  $check.closest('.gridFriend').siblings('.gridFriend').find('li').animate({
    opacity: '0.2'
  }, 1000);
  if ($(':checked').length == 3) {
    $check.closest('.gridFriend').find(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
    $('li:has(:checkbox:not(:checked))').animate({
        opacity: '0.2'
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bzuC/26/)

Comment: think you're the closest, but if I understood well, the OP wants that if you check a checkbox in the first row, the checkboxes in the 2nd row get disabled and vice versa... (though the question is not very clear)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
var mergeFriend = 0;
$('ul#gridFriend input').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        mergeFriend++;
    } else {
        mergeFriend--;
    }
     if (mergeFriend >= 3) {
        $(this).closest('ul#gridFriend').find("input:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
       $(this).closest('ul#gridFriend').find("input:not(:checked)").closest('li').animate({opacity:'0.2'},1000);
        //$('.blkSheet').css('display','block');
    } else {
        $('ul#gridFriend input:not(:checked)').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('ul#gridFriend input:not(:checked)').closest('li').animate({opacity:'1'},200);
        /*$('.friendMergeCont').animate({bottom:'-100px'},200)
        $('.blkSheet').css('display','none');*/
       }
    /* $('.friendMergeCont span.close').click(function(){        

        $('.friendMergeCont').animate({bottom:'-100px'},200)
        //$('.blkSheet').css('display','none');
         }) */
/*  if (mergeFriend == 2) {
        $('.friendMergeCont').animate({bottom:'0'},200)
    }else if (mergeFriend == 1) {
        $('.friendMergeCont').animate({bottom:'-100px'},200)
    }   */

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use Radio Buttons instead of Checkboxes if you only want 1 answer (don't understand your question clearly). Check this link for an example of [Radio Buttons](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio).